# Why does chrome web server take too long to respond?

Tags: google-chrome, webserver

When I try to go to my Web Server for Chrome in Google Chrome, it says it takes too long to respond. Using localhost does work, but my own IP doesn't. I need to be able to do it with my own IP as I want to use it with the AirConsole developer simulator

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: what happens if you ping the web server from your terminal / console? can you make a connection (`ping IP_ADDRESS`)

Comment: @MichaelLihs `Pinging with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from : bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from : bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=64
Reply from : bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from : bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for :
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 18ms, Average = 12ms`

Comment: what is your web server?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Web Server for Chrome only listens on the loopback address (127.0.0.1). To get it to listen on your LAN address, check the checkbox that says Accessible on Local Network then stop and start the server again using the switch at the top.

[image: checkbox]

You should see your LAN address in the Web Server Url(s) list now.

[image]

Comment: I happened to have been using the wrong address... it does work with the one that appeared in the list, I still can't reach it via my phone or the airconsole simulator...

Comment: I would temporarily turn off your firewall to see if that's what is blocking. If it works, you just need to allow port 8887 through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of devices using your router. Usually you can type in your router IP in the search bar and review the settings. Otherwise, restart the router as this will flush the cache and may start running smooth again.

Answer (score -1):

Restart your router,
because You router can gain too much cache after too much data transferring I think,
that will resolve your issue

Comment: How is this answer any different from [the existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41007316)?